# how to get one string / value from an Array which has the same name but has a different type using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, filter

example:

```
  let before = [ "apple.jpg", "apple.png", "apple.svg" , "banana.png", "banana.jpg" ]
```

what I want:

```
 let after = ["apple.jpg", "banana.png"]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do You mean first shown type? Change the sequence in before will impact the after array?

Comment: Yes, it can be displayed first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const before = ["apple.jpg", "apple.png", "apple.svg", "banana.png", "banana.jpg"]

const after = before.reduce((res, str) => {
  return res.concat(
    // If some element in the result array already matches the current one, don't add it
    res.some(x => x.split('.')[0] === str.split('.')[0]) ? [] : [str]
  )
}, []);

console.log(after);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a map which is having file names as keys and files with the same name as values

```js
let before = [ "apple.jpg", "apple.png", "apple.svg" , "banana.png", "banana.jpg" ]

const fileMap = {};

before.forEach(file => {
    const fileName = file.split('.')[0];
    if (fileMap[fileName]) fileMap[fileName].push(file);
    else fileMap[fileName] = [file];
});
```

After this step you will get an object (fileMap) like this

```js
{
    apple: ["apple.jpg", "apple.png", "apple.svg"]
    banana:  ["banana.png", "banana.jpg"]
}
```

Then you can iterate over this object and get the desired result

```js
const result = [];
Object.keys(fileMap).forEach(key => {
    if (fileMap[key].length > 1)
        result.push(fileMap[key][0]);
});

console.log(result); // ["apple.jpg", "banana.png"]
```

Comment: What if there is only one of its kind in the list , say cat.png .Shouldn't it add it in the result? I think you dont need if condition over there

Comment: The question says how to get one string / value from an Array which has the same name but has a different type. So I guess there are files with same name but different extensions. You are right in the case we want unique files also, we don't need the if condition

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `Array.filter`by taking closure of `Set`, Here is working example:

```js
var before = [ "apple.jpg", "apple.png", "apple.svg" , "banana.png", "banana.jpg" ];

var after = before.filter((s=>(elem)=>(frt=elem.split('.')[0], !s.has(frt) && s.add(frt)))(new Set));

console.log(after);
```